# Microsoft Graph To Do API returns status code 500

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-todo

I have the application for MS ToDo users. Some users get *"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."* error.

Request:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>\r\n  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-09-06T05:25:48",
            "request-id": "4731323d-98ef-4867-9bc2-1e8fe8b5e6a2",
            "client-request-id": "4731323d-98ef-4867-9bc2-1e8fe8b5e6a2"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

By the way, the old outlook tasks API works for users who have this error.

Comment: Can you provide full request details, how you are sending ?

Comment: @UrjaSatodiya I'm testing it using Postman. URL: GET graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists Headers: Authorization: Bearer _token_. Just this.

Comment: Ok, I just opened the url you provided in browser withour Auth token and getting related error `InvalidAuthenticationToken`. So, there May be something missing in your request.

Comment: I'm getting the same error both from my app, and from Graph Explorer ... logged in, with a valid token, and Tasks.Read,Tasks.Read.Shared,Tasks.ReadWrite,Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared granted